# libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype-dev

Tags: linux, poppler

When installing the following I get an error. What does it exactly mean and how to solve it? :)

```
# apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libnss3-dev libgpgmepp-dev qtbase5-dev libcairo2-dev libboost-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libopenjp2-7-dev is already the newest version (2.5.0-2).
libfontconfig1-dev is already the newest version (2.14.2-6).
libjpeg-dev is already the newest version (1:2.1.5-2).
libtiff5-dev is already the newest version (4.5.1+git230720-1).
libnss3-dev is already the newest version (2:3.94-1).
libgpgmepp-dev is already the newest version (1.18.0-4).
qtbase5-dev is already the newest version (5.15.10+dfsg-4).
libcairo2-dev is already the newest version (1.18.0-1).
libboost-dev is already the newest version (1.74.0.3).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype-dev (= 2.13.0+dfsg-1) but 2.13.2+dfsg-1 is to be installed
```

distro

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid
Release:        n/a
Codename:       trixie
```

Answer (score 1):

The package is a [transitional package that was removed around 2023-08-11](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/freetype/-/commit/45a29b92d55464c1887959b06578bb09314b1aa5):

> debian/control: Drop transitional package libfreetype6-dev
>
> Closes: #1038235

[#1038235](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1038235):

> Please drop the transitional package libfreetype6-dev (from the source
> package  freetype) for trixie, as it has been released with bullseye
> and bookworm  already.

As there's no reason to keep this package around anymore, just don't attempt to install it. Instead install what it depended upon: the package `libfreetype-dev` which meanwhile got newer versions.

If you attempt to build using external source packages or old Debian sources, you might have to edit the `debian/control` file to reflect the change, or use the `-d` option of `dpkg-buildpackage` to ignore the build dependency in the control file.